# When select from insert into returns no values do something different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert rows into a table. The table is empty when I start. My query is as follows:

```
Select TOP 1 *
INTO #Result
FROM #SmallTable
WHERE CategoryID=11
ORDER BY ExpValue DESC;
```

It works flawless. But I want now to account for the case where the this returns no value. But I'm not sure how to approach this.

I could either make a case and select and ask if `SELECT TOP 1` returns any values. Or I could check after I insert if there is a value present. But which approach would be better? Or is there an even better one?

Comment: What do you want to do in the case where there is no data to insert?

Comment: Then a dummy value with categoryid 11 is to be inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a union trick here to insert a dummy value should the first query not return any records:

```
INSERT INTO #Result (col)
SELECT TOP 1 col
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 col, 1 AS pos FROM #SmallTable WHERE CategoryID = 11 ORDER BY ExpValue DESC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'NA', 2
) t
ORDER BY pos;
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually brings me to a much simpler solution. Since the dummy value has a 0 i can just insert it into #smalltable because i take the top value for the category anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

This returns the number of rows affected by the last procedure.

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0  
PRINT 'Warning: No rows were inserted';
```

Comment: Will this work also inside a script where i have multiple selects and it will only take the last select?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
select top (1) coalesce(st.CategoryID, 0) as CategoryID, . . 
into #destination
from ( values (11) 
     ) t(CategoryID) left join
     #SmallTable st
     on st.CategoryID = t.CategoryID
order by st.ExpValue desc;
```